Why does preventDefault() is not always working in an iframe?
I am making a website that generates HTML documents using AI. This document is then placed into an iframe in order to visualize it. Above the iframe, there is an input acting like a search bar : you write the description of a website or its (fictive) URL. There is the problem : if I don't capture the click on a link, as it is probably fictive, it will change the iframe src attribute and not display anything.
Here is my current HTML ({{ html|safe }} is used in flask to be replaced with the generated HTML) :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebGen AI - Create your website using AI !</title>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="refreshIframe();">
    <div class="search-bar-top-fixed">
        <p class="name">Webgen AI</p>
        <form method="POST" id="searchForm" action="/c" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(event)">
            <input type="text" id="prompt" name="prompt" class="search-box" placeholder="Describe the website you'd like to generate..." value="{{ url|safe }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="current_url" name="current_url" value="{{ url|safe }}">
            <button type="submit" class="button">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <iframe class="content-frame" id="content-frame" style="position:absolute;top:100px;" srcdoc="{{ html|safe }}
    
    <script>
        function loaded() {
            const contentFrame = document.body;
        let currentUrl = '';

        try {
            currentUrl = window.parent.document.getElementById('current_url').value;
        } catch (e) {
            currentUrl = '';
        }
        
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        
        links.forEach(link => {
            let href = link.getAttribute('href');
            
            if (currentUrl && href && !href.startsWith('http')) {
                try {
                    const absoluteUrl = new URL(href, currentUrl).href;
                    link.setAttribute('href', absoluteUrl);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            }
        
            link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const searchBar = window.parent.document.getElementById('prompt');
                searchBar.value = this.getAttribute('href');
                window.parent.document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();
            });
        });
        }
    </script>
    
    ">
        
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>

Note that the javascript used to catch the click on a link is inside the srcdoc attribute for simplicity. In the flask code, I also ensured that body always has onload="loaded();".
When I click on a defective link, it first tells me that it cannot resolve URL host etc. When I get back and re-click on that link, it is catched and the default behavior is prevented.
Here is a github gist with some real content in it : https://gist.github.com/dapsvi/259e614151d4e4d3b1a86b54f4e165a9
I added some other codes in the same script but none of it was executed.
I tried to refresh the iframe when it is loaded, but this doesn't work. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Sometimes it does not work, but when I refresh the iframe manually it works. I am very confused.

have you observed any errors in the browser developer console?

Well no, and this is also why I don't understand the problem...
